# Sinatra-cache work well?

Tags: ruby, caching, sinatra

I installed sinatra-cache gem and make sure cache file is created.

But every time I access this page , cache file's timestamp is updated.

I don't think it is calling cache file when I access 2nd time.

Does anybody have any idea how it works ?

Comment: Seems like the [entire implementation is 1 file](https://github.com/kematzy/sinatra-cache/blob/master/lib/sinatra/cache/helpers.rb), so if nobody helps out you can always just read it.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you set [`cache_control`](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Cache%20Control) in sinatra? Adding gem is not triggering caching itself.

Comment: I think cache_control is client side.(https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching?hl=en#cache-control). I want to avoid many access to DB at Server.